# Count parents XML until second last layer

Tags: c#, xml, count, parent

I am trying to count all parents until the second-last layer (person). I have made an example for this post, but eventually I have a generated XML file. So the best answer is a dynamic solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data name="data_resource" friday="no">
    <persons>
        <person>
            <name>Jack</name>
            <age>22</age>
            <pob>New York</pob>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Guido</name>
            <age>21</age>
            <pob>Hollywood</pob>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Michael</name>
            <age>20</age>
            <pob>Boston</pob>
        </person>
    </persons>
    <computers>
        <computer>
            <name>My-Computer-1</name>
        </computer>
    </computers>
</data>
```

To clarify what I want: Count: data, persons, computers and person(x3). The result for this particular example would be: 7

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: You should explain exactly what number/result you want to get out of this.

Comment: "am trying to count all parents until the second-last layer (person)." kind of unclear. 2nd layer from top or bottom? all element above? a breadcrum trail to the elements on the 2nd level?

Comment: I added a result with the question

Answer (score 1):

Create a recursive function that takes an XmlElement or XElement as Parameter:

```
public int CountParents(XmlNode el)
{
    if (el.ParentNode == null)
        return -1;  // Adjust this value in order to have the correct Level.
    return CountParents(el.ParentNode) + 1;
}
```

Adjust the return value for the top level so that the result suits your needs.

Comment: I tried to implement this, but it seems that it is wrong. At (el As XmlElement). I do have the System.Xml namespace in my project. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, mixed some VB.NET in the code. I corrected the code and changed XmlElement to XmlNode; also el.Parent to el.ParentNode.

Comment: It may be a cleaner programming model to pass in the element at which the algorithm should stop at, rather than specifying a level.